# Relative Path not for a File but for a Working directory JAVA JAR Runnable

Tags: java, jar, path, relative-path, runnable

I have to set a currentDirectory for a FileReader with a relative path. It worked fine as long as I ran the application in Eclipse, but in the Runnable JAR file it doesn't. I also use Icons and was able to fix this problem there with the `getClass().getResource`, but that doesn't work with the FileReader.
How can I fix this relative path for the Runnable JAR?
The Folder I want to set as a currentDirectory is called "Beispiele".
Thanks for your help!

```
    this.fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(("./Beispiele")));
```